# How to Make CABasicAnimation invisible outside of superLayer bounds?

Tags: ios, uiview, uibezierpath, cabasicanimation

I'm trying to move a triangle from outside of the UIView bounds into the UIView area.

I'm using UIBezierPath.

While the triangle is outside of the area, I want it to be invisible. 
I want only the part of the triangle that is inside the UIView to be visible.

Unfortunately it is visible throughout the animation (while outside of bounds and inside).

This is my code:

```
UIBezierPath *triangle = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[triangle moveToPoint:CGPointMake(X, Y)];
[triangle addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(X - (width*0.5), Y)];
[triangle addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(X, Y + (width*0.5))];
[triangle closePath];
CAShapeLayer *triLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
triLayer.frame = testView.bounds;
triLayer.path = triangle.CGPath;
triLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
triLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor yellowColor] CGColor];

[testView.layer addSublayer:triLayer];

CABasicAnimation *triangleAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.x"];
triangleAnimation.duration=0.5;
triangleAnimation.repeatCount=1;
triangleAnimation.autoreverses=NO;

triangleAnimation.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(width*0.5)];
triangleAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
triangleAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
triangleAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

[triLayer addAnimation:triangleAnimation forKey:@"animateLayer"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a reference to the superview itself, you can set the `clipsToBounds` property on it to `YES`. Otherwise, you can use the `CALayer`'s `masksToBounds` property to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
testView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```